# Magento: add to cart shows empty cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, cart

When I add a product to my cart, I get the "empty cart" page.
I run Magento 1.7.0.2.

- I have a writable session dir (var/session/) and see sess_* files being created
- I have the following cookie settings (System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management): Cookie Lifetime = 10800 (3 hours), Cookie Path = empty, Cookie Domain = empty, Use HTTP Only = Yes, Cookie Restriction Mode = No
- I already tried: Use HTTP Only = No
- The cart/checkout is set to go trough HTTPS, but I have the same base URL's for secure and unsecure. I tested this (HTTPS front end Yes and No) and it makes no difference...
- I checked the `addAction()` on the `Mage_Checkout_CartController` and it gets the params and adds the product + saves the cart
- I checked the `chooseTemplate()` method on `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart` and this gets a cart's items count of NULL, when I manually/ (hard code) change this to 1, then the cart 'filled' template gets rendered (also rendered correctly, but 'of course' no items)
- I cleared cache and session data in between testing and trying...

Anyone had this and fixed this somehow? Or any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Is your shopping cart page using an HTTPS connection by chance?

Comment: @Axel - On live environment it is set to go trough HTTPS, so this is also the setting for my local environment. But on local, I have the same base URL's for secure and unsecure. I tested this (HTTPS front end Yes and No) and it makes no difference... (Updated the question)

Comment: do you have any custom modules? If so, disable all of them by moving them away from `app/etc/modules/` (not through admin) and see if it solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solutions worked for us. This is a late answer and I still consider to post an answer to this question so that it may help other people who are still stuck and looking for more solutions to try.

First we switched our domain to www which caused this problem. We fixed that problem by removing the caches, sessions and cookies. But we started experiencing that problem again and we thought that it was complex situation for us since we changed some javascript, www and SSL. But finally we found out that some products had 0 quantity and we were unable to add to cart. The cart page was hiding the out of stock message as error since it was ajax cart page through another module and theme. Then We set correct quantities for those items and the empty cart page is gone.